how to get jinja formatter working in vs code or Pycharm?
I am working on flask project where the template engine is jinja. For past few weeks, I am having a horrible experience with Jinja HTML file formatting. I can track start and ending tag and that is why, I am facing a lot of troubles.
TO get around of this, I have tried to switch from Pycharm to Webstorm but I do not have any luck. Can you please help by suggesting a formatter for jinja html in either vs-code or pycharm? I have both community and professional edition of Pycharm.

